# My Boolean Field is showing blank in django-admin list_display

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a boolean field in my model, named `paid_status` and I want this field to be editable in list display.
My model looks like this:

```
class InvoiceInfo(BaseModel):
invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False, blank=False, default="")
delivery_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
net_payable_amount = models.FloatField(default=0, null=False, blank=False)
paid_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
ONLINE_PAYMENT = 'SSLCOMMERZ'
CASH_ON_DELIVERY = 'CASH_ON_DELIVERY'
PAYMENT_METHOD = [
    (ONLINE_PAYMENT, 'SSLCommerz'),
    (CASH_ON_DELIVERY, 'CashOnDelivery'),
]
payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PAYMENT_METHOD, default=CASH_ON_DELIVERY)
order_number = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='invoice', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return 'OrderId: ' + str(self.order_number) + "  " + "InvoiceNumber: " + str(self.invoice_number)
```

And my admin.py looks like this:

```
class InvoiceInfoAdmin(MaterialModelAdmin):
list_display = ['id', 'invoice_number', 'order_number', 'delivery_date_time',
                'paid_status', ]

search_fields = ['invoice_number', 'order_number__pk']
list_editable = ('paid_status',)
list_filter = ['created_on', 'delivery_date_time']

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if obj.id:
        obj.modified_by = request.user
    obj.created_by = request.user
    obj.save()
    return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

but when I do this, the `paid_status` field becomes blank in my admin panel; how can I fix this?
Screenshot for reference:
[image]

P.s. I am using material admin

Answer (score 0):

I hope everything is correct, it may be issue of material admin, you can confirm this by connecting to your database by either pgadmin4 or by psql and check if False is there in database, i'm sure its material admin issue

Comment: if I remove paid_status fro list_editable the values show perfectly. The problem occurs when I try to make this editable in list view.